# Datatables FixedColumns With "nowrap" Requirement

Tags: jquery, datatables, nowrap

I have a large tabular amount of data where the leftmost column needs to always be displayed and where each row should take up only one line - which can be achieved with the CSS directive `white-space: nowrap`.

I have chosen the [DataTables jQuery plugin](http://datatables.net/) along with its [FixedColumns extension](http://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/), which fits the bill quite nicely for what I'm looking to do.

However, Internet Explorer (version 11 is what I have at hand)  I see that the grid does not align correctly - the fixed column has a scroll bar of its own and the table headers no longer perfectly align with their corresponding columns.

I have created a JSFiddle to demonstrate the issue -  http://jsfiddle.net/tczwysao/11/. You can see that if you comment out the white-space directive then the columns then line up. But I do need the leftmost column to stay on the one line.

Is there an error in the way I have implemented this or can anyone suggest a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to load Bootstrap and add appropriate table classes `table table-striped table-bordered`.

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tczwysao/9/) for demonstration of corrected code.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the height of `DTFC_LeftBodyWrapper` and `DTFC_LeftBodyLiner` are getting set incorrectly in one of your plugins (that's the scroll bar issue). If you go in there with firebug and remove the set height on those elements, the bar disappears..

As for the column headers, this is a pretty awful hack, but I put some padding around the header and it was able to set the width of the headers right.

```
<th class="fixed-column" style="padding: 0 70px">Fixed Column</th>
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/tczwysao/7/ looking good in firefox to me, but I do feel a bit greasy about that workaround.

Comment: This does indeed fix the example cross-browser, but not my real world problem so I have updated the example with a more complex table structure (and @Gyrocode-com 's table classes) to highlight the issue in Internet Explorer: http://jsfiddle.net/tczwysao/11/

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, this worked for me which fixed the nowrap issue

```
$('#table').DataTable( {
       bAutoWidth: false,
       fnCreatedRow: function( nRow, aData, iDataIndex ) {
          $(nRow).children("td").css("overflow", "hidden");
          $(nRow).children("td").css("white-space", "nowrap");
          $(nRow).children("td").css("text-overflow", "ellipsis");
          },
   });
```